# Converting characters via emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs, character-encoding

I copied and pasted the code in http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/ssft18/lec1/Prelude.agda into an emacs file, but there is an encoding problem; for example, `â†’` should be displayed →. Another example is `â„•`, which should appear as ℕ. (The same problem is presented by the code on http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/ssft18/lec1/TreeSortOrd.agda)

I have tried to convert the code in the emacs file to unicode, following the answers provided in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34585/how-convert-txt-file-to-utf-8-from-windows-1251 
It is recommended there to follow this procedure:

1. Visit the file with `C-x C-f`.
2. Revert opened buffer to the original file encoding with `M-x + revert-buffer-wth-coding-system`.
3. Use `M-x + set-buffer-file-coding-system` to set encoding to utf-8.

This had not effect.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Error shows up already in my browser - seems not Emacs related.

Answer (score 0):

From Emacs

M-x eww RET http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/ssft18/lec1/Prelude.agda

displays it correctly here.

In case of using Firefox:

The author of the page mentioned kindly commented: "I find that Firefox does not auto-detect the encoding for just play UTF-8 encoded text files.  To see it properly, choose   View / Text Encoding / Unicode "

Which makes the issue gone for me.